# Getting java.util.Calendar.YEAR in Spring message code

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, el

```
<spring:message code="footer.copyriteText" arguments="NEEDS TO BE DYNAMIC" htmlEscape="false"/>
```

I need to replace `NEEDS TO BE DYNAMIC` with `Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR)`. How can I achieve this using EL?

Comment: So you want me to change it every year for copyright year ?

Comment: Can you explain more ? Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR) is what actually I am refering to.

Comment: What issue you see ? and whats your recommended solution ?

Comment: My problem is not really with the expected outcome of Calendar.YEAR , but how to use a "dynamic" value out of java classes to use in Spring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want hardcode solution like BalusC said you can use this solution

1. Write custom jstl tag like c:set to execute constant path and return constant value then put the constant value to Page scope. This can be done via java Reflection.
2. Use the tag

   ```
   <lib:getConstant path='java.util.Calendar.YEAR' var='v'/>
   ```

And

```
arguments='${v}`
```

This solution can work with all constants and you may want change constant values without changing jsp code.