# how to access static boolean variable form jsp

Tags: java, jsp, static, boolean, jstl

Hi I have a class it contains a boolean value. I want to access its value in JSP page, if this value is false a link will show and if it true link will not show. I have also tried using getter method but it is not working, is there any way to this. My code is as below-

```
     public class Test { 
            public static boolean isMonitoringStarted;
        }
```

And in my JSP page I am trying this, but its not working -

```
        <c:if test="${!Test.isMonitoringStarted}" > 
             <a herf="#">Test</a>
        </c:if>
```

Please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Nambari: really? And whoever upvoted his nonsensicial comment: really?

Comment: @BalusC: Otherwise how container knows which package Test class is in? Will remove the comment if it is non-sensicial, no issues ther.e

Comment: It's not a bean instance so you can't do that. You could decorate it with a bean.

Comment: @Nambari: OP isn't using *scriptlets*. Please leave that dark cave and catch up with new techniques introduced along with JSP 2.0 more than a decade ago.

Comment: @BalusC: Ok, I agree it is jstl, but how container resolve Test in this jstl case?

Comment: @Nambari: just start learning JSP using more recent resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add isMonitoringStarted to request/session attribute and use ${isMonitoringStarted} in your jsp.

Answer (score 1):

Check my solution ( Use Custom JSTL function ) [Getting java.util.Calendar.YEAR in Spring message code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20436627/getting-java-util-calendar-year-in-spring-message-code/20436880#20436880)